# Cannot get Federated Identities (OpenID Connect) and Amplify to Work Without Hosted UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, line, aws-amplify, openid

I have an Amplify app and using the Amplify "Auth" object with Cognito.

My app works fine with standard Cognito user pools, but I'd like to also enable federated identities with a provider via OpenID Connect.
I've tested the provider credentials using the hosted UI, and it works fine, but now I'd like to pass the token I get from the provder into Auth.federatedSignIn(). When I pass the token I receive from the provider into Auth.federatedSignIn() I get the following Error:

> NotAuthorizedException: Invalid login token. Not a valid OpenId
> Connect identity token.

I've checked the token I get from liff.getIDToken() and it is looks like a perfectly valid JWT token.
Also, the provider I'm using is LINE. It's a popular messaging app kind of like WhatsApp, but primarly used in Asia.

This is the function:

```
async function getCognitoCredentials(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    const token = await props.liff?.getIDToken() // This gets the JWT token from the provider
    const user = await props.liff?.getDecodedIDToken() // this returns the decoded OpenID connect info like the iss, sub, exp, email etc.

    try {
      const cred = await Auth.federatedSignIn(
        'LINE',
        {
          token,
          expires_at: user.exp * 1000 + new Date().getTime() // the expiration timestamp
        },
        user.sub
      );
      console.log(cred);
  
      const authenticatedUser = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
  
      console.log("Welcome user", authenticatedUser);
    } catch(err) {
      console.log("ERROR", err);
    }
  };
```

If anybody has an idea of what the problem might be, I'd appreciate the input. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The esiest way to get the HostedUI to sliently log the user in (skip the HostedUI and go straight to provider's login page) is the code below:

```
try {
   Auth.federatedSignIn({
      customProvider: 'LINE',
   })
} catch (err) {
   console.log('LINE HostedUI error', err)
}
```

If the provider is anything but Apple, Amazon, Facebook, or Google, I've found putting  customProvider: 'PROVIDER NAME' works well.